# Create Aggregate of Boolean Values in R

Tags: r, boolean

I am pretty new to R, and I have a dataframe with four years worth of data that I am trying to create averages of. The issue I am running into is that the last column is a boolean True/False column, I want to essentially take a "vote" of the values in that column and take the majority (since there are 4 years of data in cases where the vote is split e.g. 2 true and 2 false I would like to default to true).

df = new, the ID is ctfips, so I want to take the vote of MinorityTract for each ctfips across the 4 years. (There are no missing values in my data)

```
      ctfips    year    avgpm    avg_income  ...  MinorityTract  
1   10001040100 2011    9.158084    70055    ...    FALSE
2   10001040100 2012    8.883191    74211    ...    FALSE
3   10001040100 2013    8.712092    71141    ...    FALSE
4   10001040100 2014    8.974976    61270    ...    TRUE
5   10001040201 2011    9.178633    54770    ...    TRUE
6   10001040201 2012    8.877811    49288    ...    TRUE
```

I have tried

```
new %>% group_by(ctfips) %>% sum(new$MinorityTract)
```

I understand why this doesn't work but I can't figure out a correct way to approach this.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `summarise` as the terminal step in the pipeline:

```
library(dplyr)
new %>%
    group_by(ctfips) %>% 
    summarise(vote = sum(MinorityTract))
```

Actually, there is nothing wrong with summing a boolean column, and that should already be giving the correct sums.

Comment: This worked pretty well!  It gave me the total sums in each ctfips and I'm pretty sure I can now figure out how to get to a new boolean column where the value in vote is >= 2... Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

We can use `aggregate` from `base R`

```
aggregate(MinorityTract ~ ctfips, new, sum)
```